# Determine node level in tree command output

Tags: c#, regex, tree

I'm attempting to populate a C# TreeView from the output of the DOS Tree command(tree /F /A > treeList.txt). I need to determine the level of each node in the text file line by line and store it as an integer. Is there a way that this can be determined through Regex expressions? Below is an example of the output from the Tree command:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is ****-****
C:.
|   info.txt
|   treeList.txt
|   
+---Folder1
|   +---Sub1
|   |   |   info.txt
|   |   |   info2.txt
|   |   |   info3.txt
|   |   |   
|   |   \---Sub
|   |       |   info.txt
|   |       |   
|   |       \---Sub
|   |               info.txt
|   |               info2.txt
|   |               
|   +---Sub2
|   \---Sub3
+---Folder2
|   |   info.txt
|   |   info2.txt
|   |   
|   +---Sub1
|   |       info.txt
|   |       
|   +---Sub2
|   +---Sub3
|   |       info.txt
|   |       
|   \---Sub4
+---Folder3
|   \---Sub1
+---Folder4
|   +---Sub1
|   \---Sub2
|           info.txt
|           info2.txt
|           
\---Folder5
        info.txt
```

This is an example of the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
info.txt     0
treeList.txt 0
Folder1      0
Sub1         1
info.txt     2
info2.txt    2
info3.txt    2
Sub          2
info.txt     3
Sub          3
info.txt     4
info2.txt    4
Folder2      0
And so on...
```

Any assistance or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression used to split text at beginning of node:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9][+'-_ ()a-zA-Z0-9.]*))
```

Code used to determine Node level:

```
    List<TreeItem> items=new List<TreeItem>();

    int lineNum=0;
    string line;

    // Read the file
    StreamReader file=new StreamReader("<Path>");

    while((line=file.ReadLine())!=null) {
        string[] parts=Regex.Split(line,"((?:[a-zA-Z0-9][+'-_ ()a-zA-Z0-9.]*))");
        if(parts.Length>1) {
            //Node level is determined by the number of characters preceding node text
            items.Add(new TreeItem(parts[1],(parts[0].Length/4)-1));
        }
        lineNum++;
    }

    file.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea. You may want to replace in every line of the tree's string every special character of the tree by replacing:

```
[|\\-\+]
```

and after that count spaces between beginning of the line and name of the file or folder.
Number of spaces will tell You how deep you are in lvl.
Then You also may divide number of spaces by 3 and You will get aproximately a number of lvl.
What do You think?

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I was able to determine the depth by splitting each line where the actual nodes text begins using this expression: ((?:[a-zA-Z0-9][+'-_ ()a-zA-Z0-9.]*))

Comment: @AxisMundi Still, it seems almost the same solution, but You are right, that there is need to count all characters divided by 4 in the line before file-text-node. Thx for reply.